# Move Shop By content to Right Sidebar in Magento

Tags: magento, sidebar

I have `2columns-right.phtml`. how to move **Shop By** contents [which is in left sidebar] to **Right Sidebar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  `<catalog_category_layered>` handle you need to put layer navigation block in 'Right' block as below:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Add the above xml code in your theme layout `local.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the Template Path Hint by going to the admin then navigating to System > Configuration > Developer > Debug section. When you are in the configuration page, select the store you are working in by using the top left website/store selector. Wait for the page to reload, and then select the Developer tab.

Select ”Yes” in the select box for Template Path Hints. Click Save. Go back to the store front, and reload. It says so in the template path. The immediate directory name following “template” is the name of the module through which a template is introduced. Copy the corresponding xml file from the base package to your custom design package.

In the layout updates search for .phtml file. You will find an area that looks like this: Change it to say the following instead

(Note that all you are doing is changing left to right)

```
 <reference name="left">
```

to

```
<reference name="right">
```